# AWS Http connection

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-httpclient-4.x, aws-sdk

I observed the following behavior while working with AWS SDK.

### Test Scenario 1:

Trying to download the multiple files of same size from S3 in sequential (back to back, no thread wait) calls using S3Client as singleton.(internally uses Http-core 4.3)

Result : First call to download the document takes more time(5000 ms). Since it involves Singleton Initialization etc. The rest of the calls are very fast (around 100-200 ms).

### Test Scenario 2:

Trying to download the multiple files of same size from S3 in sequential with thread wait of (10 second) between calls using S3Client as singleton.(internally uses Http-core 4.3)

Result : First call to download the document takes more time(5000 ms). The rest of the calls are not as fast as Scenario 1  (taking around 800 - 1500 ms).

Can someone suggest what is happening the background ? Is this something to do with the setting of http connection? Internally AWS SDK uses apache httpcore and httpclient libraries.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you're doing, but I believe the AWS API acts in single-batches only, even if the AWS SDK provides some method that takes in a list of keys to download, it will actually perform each download in it's own transaction sequentially. In order to actually get good performance in a situation when you need to download multiple files you need to multithread your downloader.

Comment: As an addendum, it's not really possible for us to evaluate the performance metrics of your code without you supplying the code.